# Bootstrap Timeline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap time from http://www.bootply.com/7Ewz7p4Ed5. I would like to have both right and left side panel appear on the same row. Some events have occured at the same time and so I don't want to waste space and so want both time lines on the same row. I have copied the css file of the time line. It has bit f a length :). Can someone shed some light on it please? Also, I am a newbie.

Right panel needs to be moved up to the right of left panel.

[image: right panel needs to be moved up to the right of left panel.]

```
.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

    .timeline:before {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 3px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -1.5px;
    }

    .timeline > li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 26px;
                right: -15px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 15px solid transparent;
                border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
                border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
                border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 27px;
                right: -14px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 14px solid transparent;
                border-left: 14px solid #fff;
                border-right: 0 solid #fff;
                border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
            color: #fff;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -25px;
            background-color: #999999;
            z-index: 100;
            border-top-right-radius: 50%;
            border-top-left-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        }

        .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
            float: right;
        }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 15px;
                left: -15px;
                right: auto;
            }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 14px;
                left: -14px;
                right: auto;
            }

.timeline-badge.primary {
    background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
    background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

    .timeline-body > p + p {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }
}
```

Comment: How much do you know about classes, and how they tie with css? Have you tried right-click > inspect element to try and understand what is going on with the html and css?

Comment: Not much, I am focussing more on learning a programming language and so am yet to dwell into it. So far I have understood that only the list allows you to shift the panel right or left. I tried adding a div to the css within the list so that it I could add the right panel but it didn't work. Tried a few more things but still wasn't of any help.

Comment: @RedShift Thanks, you suggestion helped. I think it is the way to go to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a solution like this: http://www.bootply.com/iqnKkVevFQ

Only as an example for the first events, check for myinverted in the css

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed and it worked fine. Thanks a ton. Can I be a little greedy and ask if I can also have one panel which starts from left and goes across the line to the right?

Comment: This could be a simple start for a one complete panel view: http://www.bootply.com/W9qEEbNqhQ

Comment: Thanks a ton. I had actually opened this question separately as well. t=you are a star.

Answer (score 2):

for saving space giv a top value to bottom right timeline event.

css

```
.timeline-inverted{top:27px}

@media (max-width: 767px)
{
      .timeline-inverted{top:0px}
}
```

in here 27px is the value bottom right timeline event goes to up.

when width below 768px there is no need top value all events are get full width of screen

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only need to do it for some panel and not on all of them.

Comment: the select all the panels all you need to do this 
and then add class to it then add top value to that class

_________________________________________
1.dont want to modify this panel
<li class="timeline-inverted"></li>


2.want to modify panel
<li class="timeline-inverted movetotop"></li>

_______________________________________
css 
_______________________________________
.movetotop{top:27px}

@media (max-width: 767px)
{
      .movetotop{top:0px}
}

Comment: thanks for your help. similar is done on the link posted below.